# How can I restrict the SELECT MATCH AGAINST to return ony results that contains all searched terms?

Tags: php, mysql

If I my term is for example *iphone ipod* the following query

```
SELECT id FROM products WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('$term')
```

will give me results that contain both terms or only one of them.

How can I restrict to show me only results that contain both terms? Speed is my concern.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `+` before every word:

```
$words = explode(" ", $term);
$all = implode(" +",$words);

$sql = 
   "SELECT id 
    FROM products
    WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+" . $all . "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)"
```

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Be sure to escape the input terms to prevent SQL Injection.